# Having a batch file get parameters from another batch file

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible to have one batch file that reads another and gets data such as a password from another? for example
batch file 1:

```
@ echo off
//get data from batch file 2
set /p pass=Password:
if pass == password goto a
if not pass == password goto b
:a
//something that happens if password is good
pause
exit
:b
echo wrong password
pause
exit
```

batch file 2:

MyPassword

Comment: Having your password by itself in a file would not be considered a batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are passed in batch over the way they are `call`ed/`start`ed:

bat1.bat:

```
set /p input= Parameter to pass here:
start "Title here" bat2.bat %input%
```

bat2.bat

```
echo Passed value: %~1
```

The parameters usually have the indexes from 1 to 9 and 0 is "reservered" for the path of the batch-file itself.

Alternative:

You can read the output of en executable using for:

bat1.bat

```
echo This will be displayed in bat2
```

bat2.bat

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('bat1.bat') do echo %%i
```

Where the second batch file reads the output of the first one and outputs it. The addition `tokens=*` is needed as it will then read all the output.

Feel free to ask questions if something is not clear :)