# How do I return a variable from a called batch file to the caller?

Tags: windows, batch-file, call

I want to be able to call a batch file like it were a function in Java or something of the like. Would it be possible to do something such as

set answer=call Calculate.bat %input1% %input2%

Where calculate.bat would calculate the sum of the two inputs, then it would assign it to the answer variable in the original batch file. Is this possible in some way?

Comment: When you `call` another batch file, it runs in the current instance of the command interpreter.  So if it sets a variable, that variable will still be set after the call returns.

Comment: Unless the second batch file also has a `setlocal`

Comment: Possible dupe of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010857/having-a-batch-file-get-parameters-from-another-batch-file/41011041#41011041) No flag as not upvoted or accepted as the user just deleted their profile...

Answer (score 1):

If you use `setlocal` in your script like @SomethingDark said, you could to decide to transmit only certain variable

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal

REM your code here, for example:
set /A "output=%1 + %2" > NUL

endlocal & set "answer=%output%"

REM variable %output% does not exist anymore
REM only %answer% remain changed (and stay the same once the script end)
```

Answer (score 0):

like @Harry johnston said, if you set a variable in the batch file you called the variable will set in the caller to. if you do not want set any variables in the batch file you call, do:

```
for /f %%a in ('calculate.bat %input1% %input2%') do set "output=%%a"
```

the output of your command is stored in `%output%`

Comment: Probably needs the addition that the result has to be `echo`ed from `calculate.bat` to read it with the loop. But I guess I would have went for this one as well :)